# Is Blazor United going to replace WASM and server

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor

As of .NET 8 Preview 7, Microsoft seems committed to Blazor United which, in Blazor team’s own words, offers the best of both worlds i.e. WASM and server versions.

Does anyone know if, going forward, Blazor United is going to be the only way to create Blazor apps or will WASM and server options remain and United be the third option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current Web App template still sets up an asp.net pipeline. That won't work for a (pure) WebAssembly app.

So we will at least need a separate WeabAssemply project type with a PWA option.

The old Blazor Server project seems redundant now.

Answer (score 1):

Per the demo video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48G_CEGXZZM

It's not replacing them so much as letting you use both of them with the same architecture and the server+client communication will determine which one it needs at the moment. It does this by having you use 2 target frameworks at the same time on build. In the video the used `net8.0;net7.0-browser` (important to note that this was 9 months ago and was still in prototype phase, I'm sure you would target .net v8 instead of v7 for the browser now).

On first page load, when the WASM files haven't been cached yet, everything will operate with SSR, then on next page load, if the WASM has cached, WASM will take over. You can also forcibly control globally or per component to use one or the other render mode. So if you have specific needs in feature functionality or performance or whatever concerns, you can bend each part to match the need.

They are also enabling other features like streaming rendering so you can get the quicker time to first frame value, while the longer to load stuff happens later, but still doesn't need a websocket to finish loading.

Comment: There are newer demos online now. And Blazor8 will kind of replace the old Server and Hosted project templates.